# setTitle extjs 5.1 removed

Tags: extjs5

I have a problem in new extjs 5.0 - 5.1 with panel set Title.
Now when I use panel's setTitle fucntion I get error "Cannot read property 'titlechange' of undefined"
In doc setTitle function was removed. How can I change title now?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

`panel.down('title').setBind({text:'newTitle'})`

Answer (score 0):

Even if `setTitle` is not in documentation is seems to work for me (example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqqc5oww/1/). I've found out lately that there is more lacks in documentation. As an alternative you ma try `panel.down('title').setText('...')` (example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqqc5oww/2/)